# How to find Basis vectors of a matrix $X$, given basis vectors of its kernel matrix $XX^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning

If we know basis vectors for $K=XX^T$ (e.g. will be eigenvectors here since $K$ is symmetric), how can we find base vectors for $X$?

Comment: Tell you what: $$ 
K \; = \; \left(  \begin{array}{cc}
  2  &  3  \\
  3  &  5  
\end{array} 
  \right). $$  Now you tell me what $X$ is and we can proceed.

Comment: *ignore if meaningless,* but can't you do [Cholesky factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) on $K$ to get $X$?

Comment: Yes, or eigen value decomposition, for $K= U\Sigma U^T$ let $X=U sqrt(\Sigma)$. Clearly, $X$ is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not generally, for example, if $X$ is orthogonal, then $X X^T = I$, and we can choose any basis we want for $I$, but that tells us nothing about $X$.

I misunderstood the question:

Since we have ${\cal R}(X) = {\cal R}(X X^T) = {\cal R}(K) $ (since ${\cal R}(X^T) = \ker X^\bot$), any basis for ${\cal R}(K)$ will do, for example, any maximal linearly independent set of columns of $K$.

Comment: To copper.hat: Thanks.  For $n\times n$ identity matrix, any set with cardinality $n$ of $n$ dimensional orthogonal vectors, is a basis set. On the other hand, if $XX^T=I$, rank of $X$ is also $n$ so the same set of basis  is a basis for $X$ as well. So I think I do not see your point.

Comment: Suppose the original matrix $X$ is orthonormal, for example. Then $K$ is the identity, and hence any orthonormal basis is a set of eigenvectors for $K$. But these have no relation to the original $X$. The point is that the 'squaring' (well, $X X^T$) loses information that cannot be recovered.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question; are you asking if given the matrix $K$ can we find eigenvectors (or some information) for $X$?

Comment: Actually I am asking if given the matrix $K$, we can find $\textbf{basis}$ for column space of $X$.

Comment: Well, ${\cal R}(X) = {\cal R}(X X^T)$, so the answer is yes. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I put a comment requesting clarification below the question. If no answer is forthcoming, it is probably time to give up on this one.

Comment: Another dead horse for my collection...